# Decomposition of a graded module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, graded-modules

In [an article](http://geometry.stanford.edu/papers/zc-cph-05/zc-cph-05.pdf) I am reading I found the following statement:

> If $D$ is a PID, then every finitely generated $D$-module is isomorphic to a direct sum of cyclic $D$-modules. That is, it decomposes uniquely into the form
>   $$
> D^\beta\oplus\biggl(\bigoplus_{i=1}^mD/d_iD\biggr)\text,
> $$
>   for $d_i\in D$, $\beta\in\Bbb Z$, such that $d_i\mid d_{i+1}$. Similarly, every graded module $M$ over a graded PID $D$ decomposes uniquely into the form
>   $$
> \biggl(\bigoplus_{i=1}^n\Sigma^{\alpha_i}D\biggr)\oplus\biggl(\bigoplus_{j=1}^m\Sigma^{\gamma_j}D/d_jD\biggr)\text,
> $$
>   where $d_j\in D$ are homogeneus elements so that $d_j\mid d_{j+1}$, $\alpha_i,\gamma_j\in\Bbb Z$, and $\Sigma^\alpha$ denotes an $\alpha$-shift upward in grading.

I have no problem in understanding the first part because it is the standard structure theorem for finitely generated modules over a PID.  But I can't understand the second decomposition:  what do exactly $\Sigma^{\alpha_i}D$ and $\Sigma^\gamma_jD/d_jD$ mean?  Does the second decomposition follow easily from the first or is it an independent theorem?  I can't find this decomposition in any other place.

Comment: It's explained right there at the end of the section you quote: $\Sigma^n$ denotes shifting upward in grading by $n$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan But I can't undestand what shifting upward in grading means.  Can you give me an example?

Comment: A graded module $M$ has some graded pieces $M_i$. The shift $\Sigma^n M$ is the module whose graded pieces are $(\Sigma^n M)_i = M_{i-n}$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Shouldn't it be $M_{i+n}$ instead of $M_{i-n}$?  So, if $M=\bigoplus_{i=0}^\infty M_i$, then $\Sigma^n M=\bigoplus_{i=0}^\infty N_i$ where $N_i=M_{i+n}$?

Comment: No. Think about $M_i$ as a "function" $i \mapsto M_i$. "Shift upward" means you want to translate the "graph" of this function to the right. This involves translating the input of the function in the other direction. For example, if $M$ is concentrated in degree $0$, then $\Sigma^n M$ should be concentrated in degree $n$, which is true with my convention but not yours.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan. This means that $\Sigma^n M$ has $\{0\}$ as submodules of degree from $0$ to $n-1$?

Comment: Yes, in my example.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Sorry, but I still can't understand.  Consider $F[x]$ as an $F[x]$-module with the standard grading, that is $F[x]=\bigoplus_{i=0}^\infty Fx^i = F\oplus Fx\oplus Fx^2\oplus\dots$.  Then, what is, for example, $\Sigma^2 F[x]$?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan And is $\Sigma F[x]$ still a graded module?

Comment: $\Sigma^2 F[x]$ is the graded module with graded parts $0, 0, F, Fx, Fx^2, \dots$ and yes, it's still a graded module.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan. But this way $\Sigma^2F[x]=0\oplus0\oplus F\oplus Fx\oplus\dots$, and this is equal to $F[x]$.  So $\Sigma^2F[x]$ is simply $F[x]$ equipped with a different grading.  Am I right?  What's then the meaning of the decomposition if $D^{\alpha_i}$ does not depend on the exponent $\alpha_i$?

Comment: Yes, all that's changing is the grading. There is no $D^{\alpha_i}$ in the notation. There are just cyclic modules in every possible grading.

Comment: @Qiaochi Yuan. Sorry, I meant $\Sigma^{\alpha_i}D$.  What's the meaning of $\Sigma^{\alpha_i}D$ in the decomposition if $\alpha_i$ denotes just a grading?

Comment: it denotes the graded module which is $D$ concentrated in degree $\alpha_i$. As $\alpha_i$ ranges over all integers you get a bunch of nonisomorphic graded modules this way. Isomorphisms of graded modules have to preserve degrees.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan. Thank you for all these answers.  I promise this is the last question, and that then I'll stop torturing you with my doubts:   Apart from Wikipedia, do you know where I can find something about graded modules?  And, in particular, do you know some book or paper in which it is explained or at least mentioned the above stated decomposition?

Comment: I don't know. The proof is probably the same as the proof of the usual structure theorem except that you keep track of gradings everywhere.